# How to store basic auth credentials in browser cache after XHR

Tags: javascript, ajax, caching, nginx, basic-authentication

**Context**

I have a friend, his name is Bob.

Bob have a server with an application running & accessible **only in local**. To access this application from the outside world, Bob installed & configured a **reverse proxy** with nginx and the module **auth_basic**.

Each request go through the authentication process by the reverse proxy. Two cases :

1. If a **HTTP GET request** contain valid HTTP header parameter **Authorization: Basic *base64credentials***, then the reverse proxy access the local application and response accordingly. Each sub-request will not require a new authentication because the browser cache the credentials and send them in every request automatically until we close the browser.
2. If a **HTTP GET request** doesn't contain valid HTTP header parameter, the reverse proxy respond directly with the HTTP header **WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="User Visible Realm"**. Then the browser automatically show a dialog box to enter credentials.

Everything works fine until here. It's like expected from basic auth specification.

**Problem**

Bob doesn't like the default dialog box from the browser and want a nice html page with a form. He configurate the nginx server to have his own html form.

The problem is that the HTML submit process for a form, by default, doesn't send the **Authorization** header parameter. Bob need to use a **XMLHttpRequest**. He implement it and receive a good **200 HTTP response** from the server when the credentials are good.

Unlike the default form behavior, with the XMLHttpRequest, the browser doesn't cache the credentials automatically in case of success. So each sub-request display again the login form :'(

Bob can't change the front code of the local application to send by himself the credentials in each request (as with a SPA). Indeed, he doesn't have access to this app. He just have access to nginx conf and his own html login form. So storage is useless here.

**Questions**

**Is it possible for bob to make the browser cache the credentials after receive the XHR response ?**

(The goal is to behave like the default behavior even when he use a XMLHttpRequest)

---

EDIT :

**Further explanation**

[image]

The local app is running on localhost. Bob didn't develop this app and he can't edit it. This app doesn't provide authentication and Bob used the basic_auth module of nginx as a **reverse proxy** to authenticate people.

It works good but use the default behavior of browsers which implement Basic Auth specification. This behavior display an ugly form and cache the credentials when success. If Bob provide his own form the behavior go, which is normal because the Basic Auth specification require specific header parameter **(Authorization: Basic ...)** that HTML form can't provide. Bob need to use XHR to provide this parameter.

The question is, how get back the good behavior of the browser with XHR ?

We can only use JS on login.html and not on the local app. Here is the workflow :

1. HTTP GET request to the server
2. Server doesn't find **Authorization** parameter OR credentials are wrong
3. Server respond login.html
4. User provide credentials by form. XHR is emitted with **Authorization** parameter.
5. Server find **Authorization** parameter AND credentials are valid
6. Server give back the local app entry file (for example index.html)
7. Browser read index.html and want request other files (img, css, js...)
8. These sub requests will fail because no credentials provide in these requests.
9. If ugly default form use, the credentials are cached automatically and it works.

I precise also that a solution would be to replace nginx basic auth reverse proxy by a real backend app and another authentication system (with cookie for example which are send automatically) which would work as a reverse proxy but it is not the question asked.

---

EDIT 2 :

**Why Bob can't use storage solution ?**

In the ulgy form scenario, he doesn't have HTML login file. When the browser client ask a request to the server, the server only response a HTTP response with the **WWW-Authenticate** header but without HTML content. The simple fact to have this header parameter display a form. Just putting the good credentials will send back a 200 HTTP Response and the browser will cache the credentials and send it in every request with the HTTP header **Authorization: Basic**.

In the login.html scenario, after a success login, we need to send back in every request the HTTP header **Authorization: Basic** (**not a cookie, because it's how work Basic Auth spec and Bob doesn't have any backend, just the nginx module**). It's possible to send this header from the login.html because we can attach JS on it. But then, the next pages respond by the server will be HTML files from the local app, where Bob doesn't have access to their HTML and can't attach JS on them to provide header **Authorization: Basic** for the next requests. A cookie could be stored from the login.html file, but this cookie need to be retrieved from the other pages and used to send header **Authorization: Basic**, which is impossible because Bob doesn't have access to the JS of these pages.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem @ElJackiste?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using ajax, just have javascript set and read a cookie:

(I use jQuery here, for simplicity, replace the ajax call with the appropriate syntax if you're not using jQuery):

```
function getCookie(cookiename) {
    /* a function to find a cookie based on its name */

    var r = document.cookie.match('\\b' + cookiename + "=([^;]*)\\b");
    // document.cookie returns all cookies for this url
    return r ? r[1] : undefined;
    // return the regex capture if it has content, otherwise return undefined
}

function getData(auth_basic) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'url_of_nginx...',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth_basic
        } // send auth header on xmlhttprequest GET
    }).next(function ajaxSuccess(data) {
        // data from the nginx
        document.cookie = '_auth_cookie=' + auth_basic;
        // store my auth in a cookie
    }, function ajaxFailed(jqXHR) {
        // do something on failure, like
        showLoginForm()
    });
}

function showLoginForm() {
    /* function to render your form */

    // attach an event handler to form submission
    $('#submit_button_id').click(function form_submitted(login_evt) {
        // I clicked login
        login_evt.preventDefault(); // don't really submit the form

        // get my field form values
        username = $('#username_input_field').val();
        password = $('#password_input_field').val();

        // I base64 the auth string
        var auth_basic = btoa(username + ':' + password);

        // try to auth
        getData(auth_basic);

    });
}

var auth_cookie = getCookie('_auth_cookie');
if (auth_cookie === undefined) {
    // I have no cookie
    showLoginForm()       
} else {
    getData(auth_cookie)
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your time and your code with comments and everything. 
Unfortunately, you didn't understand well the problem. I precised that storage is no use here because my friend don't have access to the local app which is serve by the server after authentication. It means that my friend don't have access to the front code of the app : so he have no way to retrieve the cookie and add a HTTP header parameter to each request he will make later on. Of course using cookie or local storage would be the classic way if he didn't have this problem. Sorry, i thought it was clear.

Comment: how does he have his own html form if he cannot modify it?

Comment: He can modify his form but not the local app. I edited my question.

Comment: Yes, but sadly, it's no link with the problem. I tried to explain the best i can in my post.

Comment: I explain further with a new EDIT